# how to access rails request.host_with_port in angularjs file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an angular file set up with my view template urls that gets used in my app when setting up routes.  One of the urls will change based on the rails environment and I don't always know at least for the staging environment, what the url will be.  So I was hoping to use rails request.host_with_port but when I run it I get the error

undefined local variable or method `request'

Here's the templates.js.erb file.  Is there another way I can do this?  Thanks.

```
angular.module('jobBoard')
    .constant('templates', {
            apply : '<%= asset_path('apply.html') %>',
            detail : '<%= asset_path('detail.html') %>',
            <% if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test? %>
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api'
            <% elsif Rails.env.staging? %>
            apiUrl: <%=request.host_with_port%>'/api'
            <% else %>
            apiUrl: 'http://www.knownurl.com/api'
            <% end %>
    });
```